# Android - Get the coordinates of a pixel that was clicked with the mouse

Tags: android, coordinates, pixel, touch-event

I’m making an android app, which uses Google maps. One functionality is that the user may touch on a point of the map and retrieve the coordinates. I found a great tutorial here http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android?page=1 which shows how to implement this with a MotionEvent (you can find the code on the tutorial under "Getting the Location that was touched").

My problem is that touch events seem not to be supported by the emulator and I do not have an android device to test it anytime. So I would like to have a method, that allows me to click the screen with the mouse and get the coordinates of the pixel that was clicked (so to transform them to geocoordinates).

From my research so far I couldn’t find anything that fits and I do not no if something exists. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help u out:

**oncreate code:**

```
   mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();

           mapOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
```

**inner class for overlay that will respond to touch (click on emulator)**

```
 class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
        {   

        @Override
        public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             mc= mapView.getController();
            mc.animateTo(p);

            latitude=p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
            longitude=p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ;
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, 
                        p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                        p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return true;

        }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works great! (only tested on emulator till now) 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Done! Sorry new to the forums and I didn't know this feature. I googled it and I found it here.. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that particular tutorial will respond to mouse clicks too. After all the screen shots are of an emulator.

Just one note on the author's coding style:

whilst

```
if (event.getAction() == 1)
```

will work

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
```

amounts to the same thing but is more descriptive and better practice

Comment: I don't know if he does what I wanted in the tutorial.. I really couldn't find it, maybe my fault. Thank you for the response!